# Dotnet Core, Angular 5 SPA with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: angular, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Looking for a solution created in DotNet Core 2.0/2.1, Angular 5 SPA template (generated using dotnet new angular -o myTestapp). This SPA template would be talking to Microsoft Graph API by registering this App in Azure (Likely using Msal.JS). Had any one got this working?

The idea is to create an Admin App that creates/Manages external (Non Active Directory) users in Azure AD (referred as local account in AAD).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to [invite AAD user with Microsoft Graph](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this scenario yet. I wouldn't be surprised that you might be the trailblazer for this scenario. Perhaps you could create a DotNet Core + Angular + Microsoft Graph template. I do have some direction for you:

1. Start with the Angular 5 SPA template.
2. Take a look at these .NetCore templates for Microsoft Graph: https://github.com/chenxizhang/dotnetcore-office365dev-templates
3. Take a look at this [angular4-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/angular4-connect-sample). Use MSAL instead of Hello.
4. Create a template based on steps 1-3.
5. Post here with a link to your template that you created.